# Firebase RTDB rule prevents "set" but still allows "update"

Tags: firebase, rules, firebase-security

I am trying to allow only write / update to my firebase table only if it has a child "A_Key".  I managed to prevent "set" in the firebase rule simulator, but cannot prevent "update".  The "update" simulation is always successful.

I've tried writing this to the table.

```
{
    "objectId" : "XXaabb",
    "value" : 135
}
```

Here are my rules

```
"MyTable": {
    "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
    ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
    ".validate": "newData.hasChild('A_Key') && newData.child('A_Key').val() === '123456'"
    }
}
```

Simulated set denied.  Which is what I want.
However 
Simulated update allowed.  This is not what I want.

My desired outcome is both should be denied.

Comment: you want that in update there should be change in value of A_key as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that on set there should be A_key in the data and when updating this data there should be again value of A_key then use the following rules:

```
"myTable": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "(((data.val() == null && (auth.uid == $uid)) && newData.child('A_key').val() != null) || (((data.val() != null && newData.val() != null) && (auth.uid == $uid)) && data.child('A_key').val() != null))",
    ".read": "(auth.uid == $uid)"
  }
}
```

Bolt Equivalent:

```
path /myTable/{uid} {
    read() {isCurrentUser(uid)}
    create() {isCurrentUser(uid) && this.A_key != null}
    update() {isCurrentUser(uid) && prior(this.A_key) != null}
}

isCurrentUser(id) {
  auth.uid == id
}
```

If you want that in update the value of A_key should not change then use this:

```
"myTable": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "(((data.val() == null && (auth.uid == $uid)) && newData.child('A_key').val() != null) || (((data.val() != null && newData.val() != null) && (auth.uid == $uid)) && data.child('A_key').val() == newData.child('A_key').val()))",
        ".read": "(auth.uid == $uid)"
      }
    }
```

Equivalent Bolt:

```
path /myTable/{uid} {
    read() {isCurrentUser(uid)}
    create() {isCurrentUser(uid) && this.A_key != null}
    update() {isCurrentUser(uid) && prior(this.A_key) == this.A_key}
}

isCurrentUser(id) {
  auth.uid == id
}
```

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/bolt/blob/master/docs/guide.md

Answer (score 0):

I made one small change and now it works

```
newData.hasChild('A_Key')
```

should be

```
newData.child('A_Key').exists()
```